# outline-style different in chrome compared to firefox and internet explorer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

seems firefox and IE have a default of black dotted outline while chrome has a default of a light blue solid outline.

I tried to change that by doing this:

```
a{
 outline-style: dotted;
 outline-color: black;
}
```

this seems to do a catastrophe as suddenly all links got a dotted black outline even not hovered or focused.
this is terrible because "outline" is the only thing that can differentiate a mouse focus from a keyboard key focus.

any other idea on how to make chrome's outline look like the others ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-family: verdana;
        }
        
        .zone2 a{
            outline-width: thick;
            outline-color: red;
        }
        
        .zone3 a{
            outline-style: solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
outline tests:<br/>

<div class="zone1">
<a href="#">test link 1</a><br/>
<a href="#">test link 2</a><br/>
<a href="#">test link 3</a><br/>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="zone2">
<a href="#">test link 1</a><br/>
<a href="#">test link 2</a><br/>
<a href="#">test link 3</a><br/>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="zone3">
<a href="#">test link 1</a><br/>
<a href="#">test link 2</a><br/>
<a href="#">test link 3</a><br/>
</div>
    


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must apply rule to focus state like `a:focus` instead of `a` directly.

Comment: I don't want to use :focus because "focus" happens both on keyboard and mouse focus.
I want to capture only keyboard focus and it seems only "outline" can do that and only sometimes.

Comment: Well i hope you know that focus with mouse is `:hover` which is different than `:focus`